# How to allow "*" and number only in Regular Expression : Qt5.2

Tags: regex, windows, ip-address, qregexp, qt5.2

I want to allow `*` or Number only in my `QLineEdit` for IP Address.

My regular Expression is:

`QRegExp rx ( "^(0|[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))$" );`

Which is find for `IP Address`, Now I want to allow `*` symbol for search IP Range.

i.e. `10.105.*.*` to `10.107.*.*`
This treated as `10.105.0.0` to `10.107.255.255`

Comment: use `\*` and it will work

Comment: Example: `print re.match("^(0|[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])).1[0-9]{1,2}.(\*|[0-9]{1,3}).(\*|[0-9]{1,3})$","10.105.*.*")`

Comment: I have tried like this `( "^(\*|0|[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))$" )` but, it wont work.

Comment: Can you give us your complete code? If you are trying to match `"^(\*|0|[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))$"` with `"10.105.*.*"` it will fail

Comment: I have made custome IPAddress using QLineEdit and QLabel. This RegExp is for single block of ip address. I am using four QLineEdit and three QLabel to make single IP Address. QlineEdit for geting digit(ip) then QLabel for `dot`. (QLineEdit QLabel QLineEdit QLabel like this)

Comment: try to add `\\*` or even `\\\\*`

Comment: Both tried...:) It wont work.

Comment: On your RegEx, are you using `.`(dots)? If yes, replace them by `\\.`

Comment: No, I am not using .(dots), My RegEx allow Numbers only as per IP Range, like at value 0-255.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `Regex` which matches IPAddress with * and/or between 0-255

```
Regex reg = new Regex("^((\\*)?|[01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.((\\*)?|[01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.((\\*)?|[01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.((\\*)?|[01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$");

bool isMatch = reg.IsMatch("*.1.1.255"); //true
isMatch=reg.IsMatch("255.255.255.255"); //true
isMatch=reg.IsMatch("*.*.*.*"); //true
isMatch=reg.IsMatch("0.0.0.0"); //true
isMatch=reg.IsMatch("256.*.*.*);//false
isMatch=reg.IsMatch("2.2.455.*);//false
```